# Entity framework - Save changes issue

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

Im using MySQL, MVC + EF6(database first) for my personal blog project. (Im new in asp, ORM etc.)

This is a part of my db schema.
[image]

When i tried to save my Article with method SaveChanges i receive an error.

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException. An error occurred
>   while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for
>   their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null
>   because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the
>   exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by
>   exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the
>   InnerException for details.

InnerException

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(SELECT\n`article_has_category`.`Article_Id`,
>   \n`article_has_category`.`Category_I' at line 1

I checked the model and schema. (Looks fine)

My first idea was: The **\n`** characters "eats" rest of the SQL command. : ) ...but im not sure.

My "Add" method is:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(articles article, FormCollection collection)
    {
          UnitOfWork u = new UnitOfWork();                 
          string[] categoryArray = collection["Category"].Split(',');

         int i = 0;
         foreach (string s in categoryArray)
         {
               i++;
               if (s == "true")
               {
                     article_categories c = u.Article_categories.Get(i);
                     article.article_categories.Add(c);
               }
         }                
         article.Autor_Id = 1;
         article.Date = DateTime.Now;
         u.Articles.Add(article);
         u.Complete();  //include saveCanges method
         return View("Index", "Blog");
    }
```

My articles class:

```
public partial class articles
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public articles()
        {
            this.messages = new HashSet();
            this.article_categories = new HashSet();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Titulek je povinný")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        public string Perex { get; set; }

        [AllowHtml]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Autor_Id { get; set; }
        public string Image_Name { get; set; }

        public virtual users users { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection messages { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection article_categories { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks for your time : )

Comment: Can you provide generated Articles class of your MyData model?

Comment: Yes, i added it into my question.